# Maven: compile aspectj project containing Java 1.6 source

Tags: java, maven-2, aop, aspectj

### Primary Question

What I want to do is fairly easy.  Or so you would think.  However, nothing is working properly.

**Requirement:**
Using maven, compile Java 1.6 project using AspectJ compiler.

**Note:**
Our code cannot compile with javac.  That is, it fails compilation if aspects are not woven in (because we have aspects that soften exceptions).

---

***Update 2/21/2011:***
There are two equally viable solutions to this (both cases use the *aspectj-maven-plugin* in conjuction with the *maven-compiler-plugin*):

1. Add
       `<failOnError>false</failOnError>`
       to the compiler plugin (thanks
       [Pascal Thivent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/70604/pascal-thivent))
2. Add `<phase>process-sources</phase>`
       to the aspectj compiler plugin
       (thanks [Andrew Swan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10433/andrew-swan))

More info on these solutions is in the answer section. I believe solution #2 is the better approach.

---

### Related Questions

**Questions (based on failed attempts below):**

1. How do you get maven to run the aspectj:compile goal directly, without ever running compile:compile?
2. How do you ignore the failure of compile:compile?
3. How do you specify a custom compilerId that points to your own ajc compiler (that is make compile:compile use an aspectj compiler other than the plexus one)?*

Thanks for any and all suggestions.  These are the things I've tried that have led to my problem/questions:

---

**Attempt 1 (fail):**
Specify aspectJ as the compiler for the maven-compiler-plugin:

```xml
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.2</version>
<configuration>
 <source>1.6</source>
 <target>1.6</target>
 <compilerId>aspectj</compilerId>
</configuration>
<dependencies>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
  <artifactId>plexus-compiler-aspectj</artifactId>
  <version>1.8</version>
 </dependency>
</dependencies>
</plugin>
```

This fails with the error:

`org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.CompilerException: The source version was not recognized: 1.6`

No matter what version of the plexus compiler I use (1.8, 1.6, 1.3, etc), this doesn't work.  I actually read through the source code and found that this compiler does not like source code above Java 1.5.

**Attempt 2 (fail):**
Use the aspectJ-maven-plugin attached to the compile and test-compile goals:

```xml
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.3</version>
<configuration>
 <source>1.6</source>
 <target>1.6</target>
</configuration>
<executions>
 <execution>
  <goals>
   <goal>compile</goal>      
   <goal>test-compile</goal> 
  </goals>
 </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

This fails when running either:

`mvn clean test-compile

mvn clean compile`

because it attempts to execute compile:compile before running aspectj:compile.  As noted above, our code doesn't compile with javac--the aspects are required.  So mvn would need to skip the compile:compile goal altogether and run only aspectj:compile.

**Attempt 3 (works but unnacceptable):**

Use the same configuration above but instead run:

`mvn clean aspectj:compile`

This works, in that it builds successfully but it's unacceptable in that we need to be able to run the compile goal and the test-compile goal directly (m2eclipse auto-build depends on those goals).  Moreover, running it this way would require that we spell out every goal we want along the way (for instance, we need resources distributed and tests to be run and test resources deployed, etc)

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16248351/59087

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Version 1.3 of the AspectJ plugin deliberately changed the default phase of its compile goal from `process-sources` to `compile`, see [MASPECTJ-13](https://web.archive.org/web/20150508025455/https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MASPECTJ-13). This causes follow-up problems like yours or [MASPECTJ-92](https://web.archive.org/web/20150507002003/https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MASPECTJ-92). To restore the previous behaviour of running ajc before javac, you just need to add a "phase" tag to the relevant "execution" tag, like this:

```xml
<execution>
    <phase>process-sources</phase> <!-- or any phase before compile -->
    <goals>
        <goal>compile</goal>
        <goal>test-compile</goal>
    </goals>
</execution>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting! Although I posted this question about a year ago and I'm far removed from the project that had the original problem (we've switched from Maven to Ivy!), I think your solution might work. When I get a chance, I'll set up a test environment and give it a go!

Comment: your solution worked, perfectly. I also looked at the discussion you linked and I tend to agree with you, the change they made seems more problematic than helpful. At first, I thought it was "a bit of a hack" to bind to the process-sources phase but after more thought, it makes perfect sense—AspectJ is weaving the source code before compilation! I'm changing my accepted answer because I think this is a better approach.

Answer (score 4):

How about telling maven-compiler-plugin to skip all *.java files and let aspectj-maven-plugin do the job ?

```xml
...
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
        <encoding>utf-8</encoding>
        <complianceLevel>1.6</complianceLevel>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>compile</goal>       <!-- weave main classes -->
            <goal>test-compile</goal>  <!-- weave test classes -->
          </goals>
        </execution>
       </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I haven't looked at this problem in a while but I think what you've written here is an excellent option that might exactly solve it.

I'd have to test it to be sure that calling "mvn compile" would still invoke the aspectj compiler. Also, I'd have to check that excluding java files from the compiler plugin doesn't indirectly exclude them from the aspectJ compilation.

We're currently working on another area of the project but the next time I open the middleware code, I'll test out your suggestion. Thanks! I think it's going to work.

Comment: I tried it in my maven module and it worked. Although finally resigned from excluding such this because of other reason. My project uses national characters and aspectj-maven-plugin seems to mess up with encodings.
So finally I refactored module that there is no references from java to aj. Javac compiles .java and after that AspectJ compiles missing .aj files. So far working like a charm.

Comment: Did you try setting the plugin's "encoding" option to your desired value? See http://mojo.codehaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/apidocs/org/codehaus/mojo/aspectj/AbstractAjcCompiler.html#encoding

Comment: @gmale: "mvn compile" invokes the compile phase, which invokes firstly the "compile" goal of the "maven-compiler-plugin" plugin, then any other plugins' goals that are bound to that phase (which includes the aspectj-maven-plugin's compile and test-compile goals by default), so yes, it would still invoke the AspectJ compiler, unless of course you added a "phase" tag to that plugin's "execution" tag to bind it to a different phase.

Answer (score 2):

I used this configuration in a project to compile AspectJ and Java 6 using Maven:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.8</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <complianceLevel>1.6</complianceLevel>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>  
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Ref: [aspectj-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/usage.html)

Comment: This won't call `aspectj:compile` before `compiler:compile`

Comment: You have complianaceLevel 1.6.  That's the only thing I haven't tried but as Pascal mentioned I don't think this will fix my problem because compile:compile still happens first.  I wonder if there's a way to ignore the failure of compile:compile... hmmm, I'll add that to my question above.

Comment: Does this work if you shut down your IDE (ruling out auto-builds) and do a "mvn clean" followed by a "mvn install"? And how is your project packaged? My EAR project is similar to yours but doesn't compile. Does your Java code depend on the AspectJ code, e.g. call any methods introduced by ITDs?

Answer (score 1):

> How do you specify a custom compilerId that points to your own ajc compiler (that is make compile:compile use an aspectj compiler other than the plexus one)?

I don't know how to specify another `compilerId` than the ["official"](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/non-javac-compilers.html) ones. Not sure it's possible.

My understanding is that http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOMPILER-107 would solve your problem (AspectJ 1.6+ does support Java 1. 6 right?). Sadly, it's still open.

> How do you ignore the failure of compile:compile?

The [**`compiler:compile`**](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html) goal of the [Maven Compiler plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) has a [**`failOnError`**](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#failOnError) optional parameter allowing to *Indicate whether the build will continue even if there are compilation errors*.

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <failOnError>false</failOnError>
          ...
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

This could be a ugly workaround to the above problem.

> How do you get maven to run the aspectj:compile goal directly, without ever running compile:compile?

The problem is that **`compiler:compile`** is bound to the **`compile`** phase and that you can't remove a [default lifecyle binding](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Built-in_Lifecycle_Bindings). So there is maybe another option but the only one I can think of would be to turn everything *off* by using a `<packaging>pom<packaging>` and to rebind all the goals manually (at least for these phases: `process-resources`, `compile`, `process-test-resources`, `test-compile`, `test`, `package`). Schematically, something like this:

```
process-resources       resources:resources
compile                 aspectj:compile
process-test-resources  resources:testResources
test-compile            compiler:testCompile
test                    surefire:test
package                 ejb:ejb or ejb3:ejb3 or jar:jar or par:par or rar:rar or war:war
install                 install:install
deploy                  deploy:deploy
```

That could be another ugly workaround. Disclaimer: not tested but should work.

Comment: Yep. That is really annoying.  I should be able to say "compile:compile" is replaced with "aspectJ:compile." I can *kind of* do that with the <compilerId> setting.  The only problem is when I name "aspectJ" as the compilerId, it uses the plexus version which doesn't support java 1.6 instead of the aspectj plugin. I didn't know you could completely redefine phases through pom packaging! That's very good info, +1! Of course, before doing that, I'd just use solution #3 above and spell out all my goals on my eclipse run config. I'm just wondering what the so called "convention" is for solving this

Comment: Thanks so much for the extra help.  I'm going to vote up that codehaus bug when I get more time today.  It's sad their default aspect compiler doesn't support java 1.6 which was released over 3 years ago!  
Later today, I'll probably end up trying the failOnError workaround since compilation fails quickly and quietly due to softened exceptions that the javac compiler sees as unchecked. This seems to be the lesser of all the evils and possibly an "official" workaround for the codehaus/java1.6 problem.

Comment: Of course, this is only an issue when the code doesn't compile without aspects being woven in. However, that *can* happen often when using AspectJ.

Comment: @gmale Yes, I understood that. But this is a very valid use case indeed.