# aspectj-maven-plugin, declare soft how to compile

Tags: java, maven, aspectj, aspectj-maven-plugin

Is it possible to compile project with softened Exceptions (e.g.: `declare soft: Exception : execution(* *.*());`) aspects in it using only aspectj-maven-plugin ? I can't handle it... I am still getting compilation error

```
unreported exception Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

So it is compiled without taking aspects in account.

I am using this command to compile:

```
mvn clean aspectj:compile
```

and my pom.xml is:

```
<project>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>pl.group.id</groupId>
<artifactId>aop</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>

    <plugins>

        <plugin>


            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <complianceLevel>1.7</complianceLevel>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <aspectDirectory>src/main/aspect</aspectDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this question help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610633/maven-compile-aspectj-project-containing-java-1-6-source

Comment: yea, it seems to be what I need. Please post it as an answer if you want:) I dont't know how I missed it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I think there is a bug in Maven Compiler Plugin 3.0 and 3.1 because for me it works with plugin version 2.5.1. It seems that incremental compilation is broken or the corresponding switch `useIncrementalCompilation` is somehow accidentally reversed in its meaning since it was introduced in 3.1. Funnily, setting its value to `false` fixes the situation for me. Downgrading to 2.5.1 also does. In both cases I need to change the phase for the AspectJ Maven Plugin to `process-sources` as described in the question linked to by user @Gus.

**Solution A:**

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>de.scrum-master.stackoverflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-soft-exceptions</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <aspectj.version>1.8.0</aspectj.version>
</properties>

<name>AspectJ sample with declare soft</name>
<description>Demonstrates how to build an AspectJ project using "declare soft" with Maven</description>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <!-- IMPORTANT -->
                <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
                <complianceLevel>1.7</complianceLevel>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <!-- IMPORTANT -->
                    <phase>process-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

</project>
```

**Solution B:**

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>de.scrum-master.stackoverflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-soft-exceptions</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <aspectj.version>1.8.0</aspectj.version>
</properties>

<name>AspectJ sample with declare soft</name>
<description>Demonstrates how to build an AspectJ project using "declare soft" with Maven</description>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <!-- IMPORTANT - or remove this plugin config altogether because 2.5.1 is the default in Maven 3 anyway -->
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
                <complianceLevel>1.7</complianceLevel>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <!-- IMPORTANT -->
                    <phase>process-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Yes, changing execution phase of maven aspectj plugin solved the problem.

Comment: No, the execution phase is not enough in all cases, you also have to use `useIncrementalCompilation = false`. I have added my sample Maven + AspectJ project to http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOMPILER-209 and https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOMPILER-194 so as to get this fixed.

Comment: Updated links are [MCOMPILER-209](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-209) and [MCOMPILER-194](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-194), due to the fact that Codehaus no longer exists and Maven Compiler Plugin is now an Apache project.